# How to execute a command after everything else has been executed on boot?

Tags: linux, centos, hortonworks-data-platform

I am using Hortonworks HDP 2.3 (CentOS release 6.7). My requirement is to make a curl request on boot, however the command should be executed only after various other services (Ambari, HDFS, YARN, etc) have started. I added the command in etc/profile, but this doesn't tend to wait for these services to start. Is there a way I can ensure that this curl request be the very LAST command to be executed on boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it to /etc/rc5.d/S99local (assuming you want it to start at multi-user runlevel 5, and that the other services are started via init).

Comment: This helped. Thanks!